# Need Information on support for wifi roaming on Linux platform

Tags: 16.04, wireless, kernel

I need to know whether the wifi roam is supported on Ubuntu linux. Do we have any way to change or support roaming aggressiveness on linux. 
I see laptop(STA) sticks to AP until -85dbm,then it disconnects to current AP and connects to new AP.

Below are the configuration used:

```
Kernel Info : 4.15.0-29-generic
Ubuntu : #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu
Wi-Fi Chipset :  Intel Dual Band Wireless -AC 8265
Driver : iwlwifi - 4.15.0-29-generic
Firmware version  : 34.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

/sys/module/mac80211/parameters

You can try to lower number of beacon losses to get disconnected from actual AP and try to switch to another by your WiFi card, edit /etc/modprobe.d/wifi-sensitivity.conf and add those lines:
module
options mac80211 beacon_loss_count=1 max_probe_tries=1

Reboot, and check if it makes your WiFi more sensitive to AP signal changes. If not, try add another parameter to the line above: probe_wait_ms=100

On really poor signal these setting may give you no WiFi connection at all, don't panic, just set those limit a little higher, you can use two strategies, keep probe_wait_ms higher (default is 500 but you can go higher) and keep other two options low or the opposite, the two other options higher and probe_wait_ms lower than default 500.

Oh, by the way you can change all those setting "live" without reboots in /sys/module/mac80211/parameters/... directory, for example:
echo 1 > /sys/module/mac80211/parameters/beacon_loss_count
You need to be root for doing this.